# Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request for PATCH request

Tags: powershell, device

I am working on stale device cleanup script to perform cleanup of stale devices from Azure AD tenant. I am also using graphAPI to retrieve device information Via GET request which works fine.
But when I try to use PATCH/POST request to update device status, it is not working as expected and throws an 400 error message. I have tried modifying the body part and received 404 and 403 error messages as well. Can someone please help with the below function ?

```
$AzureToken = Get-MsalToken -TenantId $azureTenantId -ClientId $azureAplicationId -ClientSecret $azurePassword

$authheader = @{    
"Authorization" = "Bearer $($AzureToken.AccessToken)"
"Content-type" = "application/json"    
}


$ssoPatchUri = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/#############’

$body = @{ "extensionAttributes"= @{
                                "extensionAttribute6"= "$((Get-Date).ToFileTimeUtc())"
                            }
                            "accountEnabled"= $false
                        }
                                 
                        
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri $ssoPatchUri -Method PATCH -Body ($body| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5)
```

Error Message:

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1

- Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authheader -Uri $ssoPatchUri -Method PATC ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
  ```